# Calculating average distance

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a program that gives the average distance as the output. When I tried to repeat finding the average distance 100 times using Table, It failed to generate the output. This is the program.

```
Xarray = A @@@ Tuples[Range[0, 4], 3];
Table[M = RandomSample[Xarray, 7];
energies = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1.5], {7}];
f = {#, First@Pick[energies, M, #]} &;
list = Map[f, M]
c = Subsets[Range[Length@list], {2}];
d = Length@%

distanceBetween[{n_, m_}] := 
  Norm[List @@ list[[n, 1]] - List @@ list[[m, 1]]]

Map[distanceBetween, c]
ans = % // N;

Total[%/d], {i, 100}]
```

The program is like this. I created an array of let say 500 elements and assigned energy to it. Next I choose a coordinate from the list and find the distance from other coordinates using the norm equation. Next I sum up that distances in the list and take the average of the distance. The Problem comes when I am trying to do this process 100 times using Table or Do command.

Comment: Could you post the `Table` command you used. You should not use symbols that start with a capital letter such as Xarray or A, M as those might shadow MMa symbols.

Comment: I had posted it now.

Comment: A note, `Length@Xarray;` doesn't seem to do anything, is there a use for it ? And what is the purpose of `A`, it seems redundant?

Comment: Thanks, but your `Table` command is incomplete. Also you are assigning repeatedly a list to a single variable. do you mean `m = Table[RandomSample[Xarray,7],{100}]` or so?

Comment: I didn't edited the program. It helps me to know the number of elements in the array.

Comment: @image_doctor There are quite a few redundancies in the code. Another one is `d = Length@%`

Comment: I suggest you are thinking about what your question actually is and provide us with a working example which demonstrates where the problem is.

Comment: @Daniel, the array ( it is really a list not an array   )  knows how many elements it has, no need to use  a variable to store it... whenever you need it's length just use `Length@Xarray`

Comment: You seem to be trying to create a list of energies of `Length@M`, and `M` is a list of length 7, is that what you intend ?

Comment: You seem to be missing some semicolons in your code causing some errors when running the code (e.g. after `list = Map[f, M]` and `d = Length@%`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It is not beautiful but ...

```
xarray = A @@@ Tuples[Range[0, 4], 3];

distanceBetween[{n_, m_}, list_] := 
  Norm[List @@ list[[n, 1]] - List @@ list[[m, 1]]];

meanDist := Module[{m, c, f, list, energies},
  m = RandomSample[xarray, 7];
  energies = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1.5], {Length@m}];
  f = {#, First@Pick[energies, m, #]} &;
  list = Map[f, m];
  c = Subsets[Range[Length@list], {2}];
  Mean@Map[distanceBetween[#, list] &, c] // N]


Table[meanDist, {100}]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I see that you are at least using the answers to your previous questions to improve your code, but I do think you need to spend a bit more time with the documentation so that you better understand what you are doing. It really doesn't make people keen to help when you come back with the same problem and ask for help at every step.

Once you clean up the code with semicolons, you don't get errors any more, but the result is something like a 100-length vector where each element looks like:

```
 1/125 A[0, 0, 0] + 1/125 A[0, 0, 1] + 1/125 A[0, 0, 2] + 
 1/125 A[0, 0, 3] + 1/125 A[0, 0, 4] + 1/125 A[0, 1, 0] + 
 1/125 A[0, 1, 1] + 1/125 A[0, 1, 2] + 1/125 A[0, 1, 3] + 
 1/125 A[0, 1, 4] + 1/125 A[0, 2, 0] + <<103>> + 1/125 A[4, 2, 4] + 
 1/125 A[4, 3, 0] + 1/125 A[4, 3, 1] + 1/125 A[4, 3, 2] + 
 1/125 A[4, 3, 3] + 1/125 A[4, 3, 4] + 1/125 A[4, 4, 0] + 
 1/125 A[4, 4, 1] + 1/125 A[4, 4, 2] + 1/125 A[4, 4, 3] + 
 1/125 A[4, 4, 4]
```

I'm sure that's not what you intended. The use of `%` inside the `Table` (or `Module`) seems unnecessary and I think it is part of the problem.

If you compress the last three lines inside your `Table` to

```
Total[N[Map[distanceBetween, c]] ]/d
```

you will get numerical data of the kind I think you are looking for.

There are some other problems with your code, e.g. the unnecessary manual calculation of mean instead of using `Mean` (so you can remove the other `%`). I also think that calculating the energies inside the `Table` means that if you select the same element in more than one of your `RandomSample`s, it will have a different energy each time. I am sure this is not what you intend. The problem here is not with your understanding of Mathematica, it is with your understanding of what you are trying to do. Try writing out step by step in pseudocode or math first, to test if you have made a conceptual error in your implementation.

I'll also point out that if you hadn't given the elements of `Xarray` a `Head` of `A` using `A @@@`, you wouldn't need the `List @@` code further down in the distance between function.

In any case if you redefine your `distanceBetween` function like this, you won't need to keep inefficiently *redefining* it in each iteration of the `Table`.

```
distanceBetween[lst_, {n_, m_}] := Norm[List @@ lst[[n, 1]] - List @@ lst[[m, 1]]]
```

Alternatively, leave the elements of `Xarray` as lists not `A[1,2,3]` and so on, and you can just use the `EuclideanDistance` function instead of recoding it yourself.